# How do I get notified in my qt application about USB drive plugged in to the system

Tags: usb

I am writing an application in Qt 4.6/4.7 on Ubuntu 10.04 where in I need to copy some files from the USB drive the moment it is connected to the system. The application while it is running, should be able to detect that a pen drive is inserted and without the user intervention, should look into the usb drive for specific file and copy it to the local drive. This should happen every time a new pen drive is inserted. is there any simple method which i can use? Pls suggest.

Thanks in advance

Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Consider the hotplug mechanism. With the hotplug the kernel sends events when hardware changes its state. Usually listening to the events implies the use of the `/sbin/hotplug` script, but a netlink socket is also provided. So you can listen to the socket, filter required events and handle them.

[Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt) is a doc you can find a detailed explanation and a C code example.

Answer (score -1):

You should use udev service and define a trigger which will launch your app depending on attributes of plugged device.

Comment: What if the application needs to remain running before and after the drive is plugged in?